# Iphone can't install my app after assembling with Distr certificate in XCODE

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment

I did everything according to the instructions:
https://youtu.be/91sTQ39kkK4
For Ipad everything works, but on an iPhone - no!
I tried to put different certificates, but nothing helps.
When I use the developer certificate, the application is installed and started normally.

Any ideas?

p.s.
When i try run on Iphone, i get the following error: 
**App installation failed. A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.**

[App installation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vG7F.jpg)
[General settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcCpw.jpg)

Comment: who want to help me, please write me! Also you can write to me in WHATSAPP: +79680608071 or 89680608071

Comment: Может лицензию надо enterprise брать было за 300$, а не девелоперскую 100$?